# MFC VC++ Custom Checkbox Image

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, checkbox, mfc, ownerdrawn

How do I get a 3-state checkbox to use a different bitmap for the Indeterminate state?

I want to change the image used by my 3-state checkboxes to use a different one; the controls are in Win98-style, and the indeterminate state of such checkboxes is difficult to distinguish from disabled checkboxes (this is presumably why they changed this for the WinXP-style controls, but I cannot use those because of other details in my project).

I'm using Visual C++ 2010, and I've defined an 8x8 bitmap in VS's Resource Editor. The bitmap's ID is `IDB_INDET_CHECK`.

I'm not entirely sure what the standard "technique" for something like this is; I've only really just started getting into manipulating Windows controls and MFC.

My first attempt was to create a class, `CTriButton`, that derives from `CButton`, override the `DrawItem` function, and try to draw it myself. I then used `SubclassDlgItem` to turn one of the checkboxes in my window into this class (I think?). This... sort of works? The checkbox no longer appears, and if I click on where it should be, an empty checkbox frame appears, but nothing else happens (and the debug message in my code is not being sent).

Here's the relevant code, though I'm not sure *any* of this is right. First, code from my window's `OnInitDialog`.

```
BOOL CAffixFilterDlg::OnInitDialog() // CAffixFilterDlg is my CDialog-derived window
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog(); // call basic version

    // subclass a CButton-derived control with CTriButton
    if ( CBipedHead.SubclassDlgItem(IDC_HEAD, this) ) // CBipedHead is a CTriButton member of CAffixFilterDlg, IDC_HEAD is a checkbox
        SetWindowLong(CBipedHead.m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, CBipedHead.GetStyle() | BS_OWNERDRAW); // set the ownerdraw style
    else // subclassing didn't work
        _ERROR("Subclassing failed."); // I do not see this error message, so SubclassDlgItem worked?

    // initialization continues, but is not relevant...
    UpdateWindow();
    Invalidate();

    return TRUE;
}
```

Next, the code for my custom button's `DrawItem`.

```
void CTriButton::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
    _DMESSAGE("Drawing TriButton"); // never see this message

    CDC dc;
    dc.Attach(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);     //Get device context object
    int nWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMENUCHECK);
    int nMargin = ( nWidth - 8 ) / 2;

    CRect textRt = lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem;
    textRt.right = textRt.right - nWidth - nMargin;

    CString text;
    GetWindowText(text);

    UINT textDrawState = DST_TEXT;
    if ( lpDrawItemStruct->itemState & ODS_DISABLED )
        textDrawState |= DSS_DISABLED;

    dc.DrawState(CPoint(textRt.left, textRt.top), textRt.Size(), text, textDrawState, TRUE, 0, (CBrush*)NULL);

    CRect rt = lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem;    // initial rect is for entire button
    rt.left = rt.right - nWidth;            // set left margin
    LONG center = ( rt.bottom + rt.top ) / 2;
    rt.top = center - nWidth/2;
    rt.bottom = center + nWidth/2;

    UINT checkDrawState = DFCS_BUTTONCHECK;
    if ( lpDrawItemStruct->itemState & ODS_DISABLED )
        checkDrawState |= DFCS_INACTIVE;

    if ( lpDrawItemStruct->itemState & ODS_CHECKED )
        checkDrawState |= DFCS_CHECKED;

    else if ( GetCheck() == BST_INDETERMINATE ) {
        _VMESSAGE("Indeterminate; custom draw.");

        CBitmap indet_check = CBitmap();
        indet_check.LoadBitmap(IDB_INDET_CHECK);

        CPoint pt = CPoint(rt.left + nMargin, rt.top + nMargin);
        CSize sz = CSize(8, 8);

        dc.DrawState(pt, sz, &indet_check, DST_BITMAP|DSS_NORMAL);
    }

    dc.DrawFrameControl(rt, DFC_BUTTON, checkDrawState);
}
```

Comment: Where did you enable the owner draw window style?

Comment: What's your question? Where did you set check-box to have tri-style or set button's state to intermediate?

Comment: @paludarium: Thanks, that helps some; I didn't know to do that. I've updated my code and now set the ownerdraw style; now the thing doesn't seem to get drawn at all until I click on where it should be, and then I only get an empty checkbox frame. My drawing code doesn't seem to be called (never see the debug message). My question's been updated with this. Thanks for the mention of setting the style!

Comment: @Ajay: The checkbox was set up in Visual Studio's resource editor, including its tri-style and default state. Anyway, thanks for your comment; I've tried rewriting my question to be clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not *the* answer, but *an* answer: this custom [`CCheckBox`](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/controls/checkboxcontrols/article.php/c5297) I found more-or-less enables what I want. It doesn't, by default, allow 3 states, but I fixed that up with some of my own tweaks. I'm not 100% sure it works out of the box (I've had some issues, that don't *seem* to be due to my edits, but I can't be sure), but it was the solution I've used. I'm not going to call this the answer, though, in case someone can spy what was wrong with my code and wants to illuminate me.

Answer (score 3):

In OnInitDialog() you need to call InvalidateRect() after changing the window style otherwise it doesn't know it needs to be redrawn. It's also a good idea to call UpdateWindow() after changing window styles. Some information is usually cached by the common controls and won't acknowledge the change until UpdateWindow() has been called.

In DrawItem() you are responsible for rendering all states of the control. You should not call CButton::DrawItem() as it does nothing. Try something like the following:

```
void CTriButton::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
    CBitmap indet_check

    _DMESSAGE("Drawing TriButton"); // I never see this message
    int checkState = GetCheck();

    if ( checkState == BST_CHECKED )
    {
        indet_check.LoadBitmap(IDB_INDET_CHECK);
    }
    else if ( checkState == BST_UNCHECKED )
    {
        indet_check.LoadBitmap(IDB_INDET_UNCHECKED);
    }
    else if ( checkState == BST_INDETERMINATE )
    {
        indet_check.LoadBitmap(IDB_INDET_INDETERMINATE);
    }

    //    ... rest of your drawing code here ...
    //    don't forget to draw focus and push states too ;)

}
```

Addendum:

I can't believe I missed this first time around but your call to `SubclassDlgItem` is probably not having the desired effect. This call causes messages intended for the button to be processed by the controls parent window first. Because the default implementation of `DrawItem` in `CWnd` (the superclass of CDialog) does nothing the message never gets passed to the control.

Replace this with the following snippet and everything should be ok:

```
HWND hWndButton;
GetDlgItem(IDC_HEAD, &hWndButton);
CBipedHead.SubclassWindow(hWndButton);
```

Two side notes here:

1. It's usually not a good idea to use the same naming convention for both classes and class members. It makes for a confusing read.
2. I'm guessing you are always compiling and running in release mode. If you are - don't. This prevents assertions from being thrown and letting you know something is wrong.

Comment: `CButton::DrawItem` doesn't do anything? That's... certainly odd. Is there any way to load the default bitmap for a check mark (some default ID or something I can use with `LoadBitmap`? Also, what other things does a `DrawItem` function need to handle, i.e., did my code get all of it? One of the major problems for me here was that I cannot see the actual definition of `DrawItem` to know what I'm supposed to be mimicking... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for the note about `InvalidateRect` and `UpdateWindow`; that makes sense.

Comment: @DragoonWraith None of the common control representations in MFC implement rendering in their DrawItem() method. They typically contain one line and that's an ASSERT() statement.  The [DRAWITEMSTRUC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92fhtw0f%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) structure contains a member called _itemState_ which hold various flags about how the control should be drawn.  For all controls you should handle at least the **ODS_DEFAULT**, **ODS_DISABLED**, **ODS_FOCUS** and **ODS_SELECTED** states. AFAIK the common controls generally do not rely on resource bitmaps for their elements.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. Now to look up how to do those things... I assume that since a I want a non-default "look" to the indeterminate state, I will need a bitmap for that?

Comment: @DragoonWraith You're quite welcome. You can use bitmaps or draw it using vector based GDI calls. One thing to keep in mind is you should make every effort to maintain uniformity in the look and feel of all controls displayed in your dialogs and windows. It may take a little extra time but it provides a much more fluid presentation to your users.

Comment: Oh; I completely agree; that's the whole reason that I'm doing this (the Win98-style checkboxes have a very unsatisfactory indeterminate state, so I'm basically recreating the WinXP look for them). All the 3-state boxes in the application will use this same style. Since most users use WinXP-or-later, I suspect this will be **more** familiar than the alternative.

Comment: OK, so I've redone my `DrawItem` command, but my debug message still isn't being sent. I've added `UpdateWindow()` and `Invalidate()` to my `OnInitDialog` function, but I still just get a blank space where the checkbox should be; clicking it gives a blank checkbox but no text, and it doesn't get checked when it is clicked. Help?

Comment: Just to add to this conversation, if you're trying to overlay or draw over the old WinProc procedure for the control in Windows you just simply cannot use Invalidate or updateWindow. The reason for this is Windows windows control will for multi langual and technical reasons will call Paint out of line than you normally expect it to. Same goes for Edit control.

Comment: @Chad - he's using the custom/owner draw facilities of the button control.

Comment: But they don't seem to be working. My `DrawItem` function starts with a debug message that never gets printed. I definitely have `BS_OWNERDRAW` set, so I'm not really sure what I need to do to get the thing to call `DrawItem`...

Comment: I updated it to reflect an issue I missed the first time around.

Comment: :/ Well, changing the way I'm subclassing doesn't seem to have changed anything. I've been building in debug mode, and I do get asserts when I trigger them, so it's not that. As for naming conventions, in my head they are different, though I suppose they're not really different enough. Oh well. Anyway, I **really** appreciate all the help!